# % of allocation in a portfolio based on beta

Tags: portfolio-optimization, beta

Just an amateur investor hoping to minimise loss by using beta for portfolio allocation.

Tried using individual beta/summed beta but that would result in a higher allocation for the highest beta.

Example:
A: beta =1.2, % of portf= 34%
B: beta =0.6, % of portf = 17%
C: beta =1.7, % of portf = 48%

I'm trying to minimise loss so I'm hoping to have a higher holding of the stock with the lowest beta.

Comment: The inverse-volatility portfolio is an example of a low-beta strategy. Despite being a heuristic construction method, its formula has ties to reciprocal betas and their sums like what you're alluding to

Comment: One idea might be: if you have $N$ stocks, give stock $i$ a weight $\frac{1}{N}+K(1-\beta_i)$ where K is some positive constant. This way stocks with $\beta>1$ get a less than equal weight allocation, stocks with $\beta<1$ are overweight. The challenge would be how to choose a reasonable value of $K$, such that no stock is sold short.